# signed RSL without Flex (pure AS3 project)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, signed, rsl

Here there's a brief explanation of how we can "simulate" the RSL system used in Flex with pure AS3:
[loading an RSL without using flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201659/loading-an-rsl-without-using-flex)

But what about signed RSLs? can we use that technique to load SWZ files too? will them be cached by the player? how can we "reuse" a SWZ cached by the player in a pure AS3 project?

Thanks!
Enrique.

Comment: I thought that Adobe is the only one that can create signed RSLs, cached by the player.  I would assume that there is nothing you can do to force a SWZ file to load or cache. When the app is being set up; hidden player APIs are referenced to deal with the RSL stuff.

Comment: yes, but I don't want to create signed RSLs (SWZ), I want use them. I want to use the TLF (signed by adobe) but without Flex. Without Flex we can't use RSL, we must do something like the question answer above, that's OK for our own library, but what about SWZ? I want to use the Flash Player cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, This is the solution (not tested yet but I'm pretty sure it works)
**Example from the Adobe's AS3 Reference:**
*//URLRequest, digest property:*

```
var myURLReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
myURLReq.url = "http://yourdomain/users/jdoe/test01/_rsc/Automated/AssetCaching_rsc/test01/rsl.swz";
myURLReq.digest = "3B0AA28C7A990385E044D80F5637FB036317BB41E044D80F5637FB036317BB41";
var myURLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myURLLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
myURLLoader.addEventListener("complete", onC);

myURLLoad.load(myURLReq);

function onC(e) {
    var someLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    addChild(someLoader);
    someLoader.loadBytes((ByteArray)(myURLLoad.data)); 
}
```

So, we can load a signed RSL (.SWZ) like any other SWF, BUT! we must use URLLoader, not Loader, and provide the digest property.
Then we use Loader to load the byteArray from URLLoader.
The signed SWZ is checked internally by the Player, and if it detects is signed by adobe, then it will be cached by the Player, we don't need to do anything.
I think Flash Player checks automatically, and before loading any SWZ, if that SWZ is already cached by the player.

That's all I think.

if you want to see more details, check my reply in FlexCoders:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/159010

Answer (score 2):

Signed SWC (ie SWZ) are loaded into the flash player cache rather than the browser cache.  Therefore only uber trusted code is allowed which at the moment comes from Adobe only.

For preloading?  Only way i know is not really a way, but say you have an info page or login page before your Flex app, load the RSLs when the user is maybe reading something by including a lightweight SWF that uses the same RSLs as your main app.  Its a cheat, but seen it used when bandwidth is a minimum and want to get bang for buck when an app first loads.

Preloading any other way outside the player I could see security concerns with.

Comment: I'm not using Flex, is a pure AS3 project, and I want to use SWZ signed by Adobe, but Without Flex, because I want to be able to use the Flash Player cache. Maybe I did't explain it very well, sorry.

Comment: Substitue Flex for ActionScript project, it doesn't matter.  I will assume you are using Flash Builder, create a project, add the necessary SWZ to your Library path.

Comment: Are you sure? this is from Adobe:
"You cannot use RSLs in ActionScript-only projects if the base class is Sprite or MovieClip. RSLs require that the application’s base class, such as Application or SimpleApplication, understand RSL loading."
And I don't want to use the Flex Framework (just the TLF).

Comment: Also, I don't want a movie with 2 frames and the preloader in the first frame like Flex does (and this is neccesary for RSL). I have my own preloader in a separated SWF.